# Impedance Matching and Reflection Coefficient

Tags: power, signal, impedance, voltage-source, reflection

Consider a real signal generator (Voltage Source Vs, output impedance Zs, reflection coefficient Γs) and a load Zl with reflection coefficient Γl.

I was told that we have maximum power transfer when there is the conjugate matching Zs = Zl*. But I read also that the power matching realizes when Γl = Γs*. What does it mean?

In circuits designing, is it important to satisfy the first or the second equation?

Comment: Have you checked to be sure they are not two ways of saying the same thing?

Comment: Suppose the distance between StageN and StageN+1 is 0.0001 wavelength. Must we match? If we match, we will give up 6dB (2:1) of the system voltage gain, at each such interface.

Comment: In effect they may seem the same thing, if I use the expression Γ = (Z - Z0) / (Z+Z0), but now I have another doubt. I was told that conjugate impedance matching means no reflection, that means Γ = 0, but in this case we have Γl = Γs*, that does not mean that Γl = Γs* = 0. How can we explain this?